# How to do 'Save As' using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask for helping my code below. I got this when I recorded a macro upon saving a new file to my desktop.

I am having issues with the **Change Directory** line. This changes will happen every time a different user is using this macro which can also depend on the value of `e`.

Also, part of the filename varies which depends on the value of `d`.

Please help me improve my codes. Thanks!

```
Dim b, c, d, e As String

b = MsgBox("This file has to be saved. Click OK.", vbOKCancel, "Save to SharePoint")

ActiveWorkbook.Save

c = MsgBox("Save this file to local", vbOKOnly, "Save to Local")

d = InputBox("This shift record falls on what week?", "Save Shift Record", "YYYYMMDD-YYYYMMDD")

e = InputBox("Enter your EID", "Save Shift Record", "EID")

'this line give error ~~~~~ 
ChDir "C:\Users\ma.cristina.i.gumato\Desktop"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "C:\Users\d\Desktop\MANILA_ShiftRecord_" + d + ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Before `ChDir` call `ChDrive` function.

Comment: Check out the value of the environment variable `USERPROFILE` for the current user.

Comment: I don't see where `e` is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Dim b, c, d, e As String

b = MsgBox("This file has to be saved. Click OK.", vbOKCancel, "Save to SharePoint")

ActiveWorkbook.Save

c = MsgBox("Save this file to local", vbOKOnly, "Save to Local")

d = InputBox("This shift record falls on what week?", "Save Shift Record", "YYYYMMDD-YYYYMMDD")

e = InputBox("Enter your EID", "Save Shift Record", "EID")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "C:\Users\" & environ("username") & "\Desktop\MANILA_ShiftRecord_" + d + ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```